# LM3485 current limiter (\$R_{adj}\$) value selection

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, current-limiting

I have what I believe is a working buck converter design centered around the LM3485. It's intended to be a Raspberry Pi power supply.

The schematic is at [Pi Power schematic](http://www.geppettoelectronics.com/2014/07/pi-power-schematic.html), which I copy below.

[image: Pi Power schematic]

(note that in the image there are two errors: L1 is 15 µH instead of 33, and the MOSFET is a Si3443CDV in the latest version).

The parts selection came largely from an online TI design tool. I changed some of the values for availability and cost, and the resulting circuit seems to perform well on the bench.

But since I have some time before the first production boards come back, I've been going over and over the design with a fine toothed comb, and the one thing I can't quite work out is the selection of \$R_{adj}\$ - the current limiter comparator resistor.

According to the datasheet, the comparator compares \$V_{isense}\$ with \$V_{adj}\$, and when \$V_{isense}\$ is lower, it triggers the over-current shutdown.

Well, \$V_{isense}\$ is the voltage drop across a sense resistor, which for this design is 25 mΩ. The maximum rated current for the design is 2 amps, and the datasheet says the peak amps is \$(I_{max} + I_{ripple}) \times 1.1\$, and that for currents over 2 amps, \$I_{ripple} \le I_{out} \times 0.3\$.

On the \$R_{adj}\$ side, there is a calibrated 3.0 µA current sink that's connected on the opposite side of \$R_{adj}\$ from \$V_{in}\$.

Put it all together and the current limit should be

$$R_{adj} \times .000003 = I_{max} \times .025$$

or

$$R_{adj} = \frac{I_{max} \times .025}{.000003}$$

For an \$I_{max}\$ of 2.53A ( \$= 2.3 \times 1.1\$), \$R_{adj} = 22k\$ (roughly).

So why did TI's design software recommend 39k?

I have to assume TI is smarter than I am. What did I miss?

Comment: Go for it. Sorry. Too many cooks. :)

Comment: There! See if you like it this way - also check for errors, please.

Comment: Looks great! Thanks. I'll have to look at how that syntax is done.

Comment: Question, why are you using a sync-fet for your top-gate?

Comment: I guess I don't know what a sync-fet is. I picked it by basically searching through DigiKey. I went for the cheapest part that would meet the current and thermal requirements.

Comment: @ShannonStrutz - dude this is a standard buck converter and doesn't have a sync fet.

Comment: Is over current waveform filtered inside the chip?
In that case, you can forget about the ripple and thus go for a higher resistance.

Comment: I don't believe it is filtered. The chip is quite simple. I'm pretty sure there's nothing more than a comparator on the two inputs to do the job. Clearly TI believes the current being measured is far higher than I think it is, but I don't know why.

Comment: @Andyaka Dude, that symbol there is the symbol for a sync-fet.  Your Si3443CDV is not a sync-fet but a regular fet, the schematic is wrong.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I went for an Eagle library that had the right footprint rather than the right schematic symbol. And I guess I don't know the difference in the symbol anyway. It looks right to me.

Comment: @ShannonStrutz I checked this out and from what I can tell there is a trademark owned by fairchild for the name "syncFet" but no specific hits on a symbol that describes a special type of FET. Please explain your self. The symbol that the OP has used may not strictly represent the exact type of MOSFET implied by the part number but everyone uses this or that symbol (including the ones that are meant to show the source with an arrow on the pin) and as far as I can tell there is no specific symbol that represents a sync fet (dude).

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, a mosfet with a body diode can be represented with a mosfet symbol including a simple diode it, which looks very similar to this one.  A sync-fet has a schottkey diode in it which is what that is.

Comment: I kind of always wondered why there was a symbolic distinction between schottkey and "plain" diodes. It's not as if they have a tremendous *functional* difference like Zener diodes do. From what I can tell, they simply have improved specs. But this is drifting way off-topic.

Comment: @ShannonStrutz can you provide a link to what you claim is definitively a "sync Fet"

Comment: nope, I'm wrong :D

Comment: @ShannonStrutz This may be of interest: [Intrinsic Zener diode in MOSFET](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111485/intrinsic-zener-diode-in-mosfet)

Comment: Oh that is interesting.  I was just confused earlier because it looks like there is a schottky diode in the symbol rather than a normal diode.

Comment: What is the resistance between Vin and Adj?  Could it be 39k in parallel with that R(vin, Adj) gets you down to 22k?

Comment: According to the datasheet, both ADJ and SENSE are inputs to a comparator that presumably has a high input impedance. ADJ has the "calibrated" current sink on it as well, of course.

Comment: It could have hysteresis resistors or be a current feedback opamp with low input impedance on one of the pins.  If you have one at your desk it might be worth a measure?  http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/AN-849.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got around to actually testing this. It turns out that the current protection kicks in at around 4.25 amps with a 39 kΩ resistor. That squares with my calculations more than it does TI's.

I'm not sure at this point whether I want to leave the protection that high (the circuit is rated for only 2A) to accommodate surge capacity or reduce it. But that's another question for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations look good... It is possible that the ripple will be more than 30% in your particular configuration and the design tool is accounting for that. Can you provide more detail - e.g. a screen capture of the TI design tool that gave you the values? What is your VIN?

Also note that the current out of the ADJ pin hardly qualifies as calibrated. 3.0uA is the minimum value but it could be as high as 7uA! Hopefully you are not depending on a precise current limit...

Comment: The data sheet says to use 3µA for the calculations to avoid false tripping. The current limit function in my design is merely protective, so precision isn't a big issue. Perhaps TI is erring high to preserve the specified output? If so, it's QUITE generous to nearly double the calculated value.

Vin is anywhere between 6 and 15 volts.

I don't have a capture of TI's design, but apart from a different MOSFET (which I would assume wouldn't impact the current limiting), it's largely the same (to the nearest standard values).

Comment: Yeah, that's a serious sandbag, but who knows. The only other thing I can think of is they might have assumed you were current sensing over both the resistor and the FET rdson, which would require a higher trip point reference....

Comment: Them thinking that it was measuring across both Rds(on) and the resistor wouldn't match up with the schematic, though. Unless they made a mistake (that is, I really *am* smarter than TI :) ).